# wp_delete_term or wp_delete_category?

Tags: categories, terms, customization

Hi I need a simple piece of code to delete a category for a custom plugin, but I just found two function references that seems quite the same:

### Function Reference: wp_delete_term

Description: Removes a term from the database.

Usage: `<?php wp_delete_term( $term_id, $taxonomy, $args )  ?>`

### Function Reference: wp_delete_category

Description: Deletes one existing category.

Usage: `<?php wp_delete_category( $cat_ID ) ?>`

My question is which one I should use (just for delete a category), and what is exactly the difference (or what makes one option better than the other).

I'm thinking that the "category" is a "term" and that `wp_delete_category()` uses `wp_delete_term()` so I should use `wp_delete_term()` - I'm right on that or I'm missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`wp_delete_category()` is a convenient shortcut if you want to delete a category. Use it to type less.

Comment: So, you are saying that calling a function that calls another function just because you type less is the way to go ?

Comment: It is also more readable and easily understood, so I'd say yes, use this specialized function instead of the general one. In the end, it's just a question of personal preference!